# Importing numbers from huge text file into python array

Tags: python

I have a file that has a huge number (6 million) of values arranged one line after the other in a text file. `readlines()` reads the values as a string and the `loadtxt()` says `could not convert string to float: b'0,000'`.

My data is arrranged like this

```
0,000
0,000
6,404
.
.
.
6,725
6,257
5,977
```

how can I create an array with these values?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the comma your best bet is to import into string, then convert to numerical data after you remove the comma.

Something like this is what you need to apply to the entire list:

```
    str.strip(',')
```

where 'str' gets replaced with the variable of the string.  You either need list comprehension if you've read it into a list, a lambda function if it's in a Pandas dataframe, or a for loop.

List comprehension example:

```
    new_list = [x.strip(',') for x in old_list]
```

Comment: Strip will not help here. Likely they want to replace with periods instead of command anyway

Answer (score 0):

numpy's importers usually want to have data with period as decimal signs. Either replace all `,` by `.` in the file before importing by them or try pandas functions, where you can set the decimal sign:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.read_table(filename, decimal=',')
```